# Index if field equals specific value

Tags: mysql

I want to use a table for multiple types of data. For instance like a log table, that holds all types of different logs, but want to create an index that only indexes log_types = 'error_log'. Is that a possibility?

I know I can have an error_log table, but for the sake of not having too many tables (1 for each log type, potentially up to 10), I'd prefer to only have one table. I also know that I can create a index that can have log_types as the first parameter, but maybe one log might want to index by date created as the second parameter and another log would benefit by having user_id as the second parameter. So in that case it would be beneficial if I could create a different index for each and the index only contained the data from a single log_type, since the other wouldn't benefit from it.

For Example:

[image]

Using the above table. One query would be for log_type = 'error' from 1/1/2020 to 1/5/2020. And another query would be for log_type = 'auth' and user_id = 12. They would benefit from having different indexes. I could have an index that is indexed by log_type, created_at and another by log_type, user_id. But since the queries would be dependant on the log_type, it would make sense if there was a way to have the index only index when the log_type = 'error' and just not index any other log_type and same for 'auth'.

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data to illustrate the case.

Comment: @TheImpaler, I added an example. Hopefully that is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store all the entries in the same, single table. Now, you can create multiple indexes for each search, as in:

```
create index ix1 on t (log_type, created_at);
create index ix2 on t (log_type, user_id);
```

Now, those two indexes will cover **all the entries in the table**, and not just `'error'` or `'auth'` respectively.

But... you want one index to only cover the `'error'` entries, and another index to only cover the `'auth'` entries. What you want is a "partial index". Unfortunately MySQL does not implement partial indexes [yet]. Oracle, DB2, PostgreSQL, and SQL Server do, by the way. Maybe a future version of MySQL will add them.

The syntax you are looking for adds the `WHERE` clause in the index creation statement. For example, in PostgreSQL you can do:

```
create index ix1 on t (log_type, created_at) where log_type = 'error';
create index ix2 on t (log_type, user_id) where log_type = 'auth';
```

Now, in many cases, having as many entries in an index won't really affect the index too much, if the index starts with the main selection column `log_type`. Not that big of a deal, I would say.

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer, it is unfortunate that MySQL doesn't support partial indexes yet. I guess I will just have to use the full index even though it just adds extra weight to the database.